# Tomcat Halts After a Request

Tags: servlets, tomcat8

On my production server (Apache+ Tomcat8), after some number of request to servlet, tomcat halts and I cannot access to production server with SSH, and when I try to access web site it gives me connection time out. In catalina.out I cannot find any trace or error log. What are ways to debug this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't even access the server with SSH means your server network is down ( or get shutdown). I don't think this is a tomcat problem

Comment: Thanks @ST.Kee, Do you have any suggestions to trace the issue further ?

Comment: I think making sure your server is connected to the network would be the first thing to do. Server refuse to connect can also caused by firewall setup etc. Make sure your port is open in firewall/iptable might help too. :)

Comment: I dont think firewall is the issue, because all the other people cannot access the server from different IP addresses, if it was firewall, then only i should've got banned right?

Comment: Are you still unable to access from ssh? You might need to call your infrastructure vendor for support in that case (assuming you are using IaaS like AWS) 
And by the way, firewall can block everyone from accessing the page simply by blocking your http port. So it is not quite related to ip address.

Comment: Yes, When servlet goes down, machine becomes unresponsive, refuses to ssh

Comment: And how do you get into the machine afterward?

Comment: I let know the sys administrator and he restarts.

Comment: okay, please share what have you implement in your servlet, or at least some snippet can let me reproduce the problem. 
And even better, you can tell me what have you tried so far.

Comment: The thing is on my localhost, it never crashes it only crashes on server environment.